# Can I make a groupbox outside of a scroll area?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I have a QGroupBox with a title '123'. Inside the QGroupBox, there should be a QScrollArea. That means that the title '123' of QGrouBox should be outside of the QScrollArea.

My sample codes are as below.

```
import sys

import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        btn = QPushButton('button')

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(btn)


        groupbox = QGroupBox('123')
        groupbox.setLayout(scroll)


        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Example()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see above, now it returns `TypeError: setLayout(self, QLayout): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QScrollArea'`.

I'm just wondering if this is achievable? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to add the content to a `QGroupBox` you must do through a layout that contains the necessary widgets, in this case as it is only a widget we can use any layout, and in this layout we add the widget that this case is the `QScrollArea` as sample then:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        btn = QPushButton('button')
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(btn)

        groupbox = QGroupBox('123', self)
        groupbox.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        groupbox.layout().addWidget(scroll)

        self.layout().addWidget(groupbox)
```

Screenshot:

[image]